# Xamarin: Change auto detected link color in UITextView and keep the underline

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview

In Xamarin.iOS, how does one change the text color of the auto detected links in a `UITextView` and still keep the underline?

Currently, I have the following:

```
_textView = new UITextView
{
     Editable = false,
     DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link,
     ScrollEnabled = false
};
```

If I set the `TintColor` on the `UITextView`, then the link color changes but the underline is removed from the link. I'd like to keep the underline as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the Attribute style of TextView

```
var linkColr= UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor;
var value1 = UIColor.Red;

var linkStyle= UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle;
var value2 = new NSNumber(1);

var dic = new NSDictionary(linkColr, value1, linkStyle, value2);
_textView .WeakLinkTextAttributes = dic;
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great!